# mystery no crank, no start

Tags: starting, no-crank-no-start

So, here is the issue with my truck. Sometimes it will strand me wherever i go in the day for about 2 hours (no crank, no start). After that, it cranks right up and i can get home. its frustrating when troubleshooting because every time i do, it starts right up. here is some information on the truck.
i have a 1993 chevy cheyenne. it has a brand new battery, starter, ignition switch, and neutral safety switch. The wiring so far looks like its in good condition. I have replaced all contact wiring to the starter solenoid. does anyone have any ideas.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Maybe a bad ignition switch?